# C++ Как передать в функцию разное количество параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, макросы

Есть конструктор Simple_value, который принимает название фигуры и любое кол-во точек.
В векторе _Temp_points_for_centroid_points у меня хранятся 4 или 8 точек для разных фигур.

```
if(Tetrahedron)
_Centroid_value = Simple_value(Tetrahedron,
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[0],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[1],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[2],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[3]);
if(Prism)
_Centroid_value = Simple_value(Prism,
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[0],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[1],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[2],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[3],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[4],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[5],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[6],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[7]);
```

Можно ли сделать какой-то макрос (или что-то другое), чтобы я упростил конструкцию до

```
#define ALL_NODES(num) _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[0],  ..., _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[num - 1]
_Centroid_value = Simple_value(Tetrahedron, ALL_NODES(4));
```

Т.к. количество точек в векторе всегда известно. Поменять конструктор, чтобы он принимал не точки, а весь вектор - нет возможности.

Comment: Тут конечно можно написать соотв макрос, но зачем? Ведь вызовов конструктора всего два.

Comment: Может быть только 4 или 8 параметров?

Comment: А что такое `Tetrahedron`? и `Prism`? Это объекты разных типов?

Comment: Попробуйте передавать итераторы, если ссылку на вектор не хотите.

Comment: Или вообще `Simple_value(int n ,int * begin , int * end){for(int*i=begin;i != end;++i)(*i)...} `

Comment: @AlexGlebe менять конструкторы нельзя

Comment: Придумал только десять макросов. `# define ALL_NODES10 ALL_NODES9  ,_Temp_points_for_centroid_points[9]` и ещё `# define ALL_NODES9 ALL_NODES8  ,_Temp_points_for_centroid_points[8]` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно вот так для конструкторов с 4 и 8 точками:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>   

struct Monster {
    Monster(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4) {
        std::cout << "4 points:\n"
                  << p1 << ' ' << p2 << ' ' << p3 << ' ' << p4
                  << '\n';
    }

    Monster(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4,
            int p5, int p6, int p7, int p8) {
        std::cout << "8 points:\n"
                  << p1 << ' ' << p2 << ' ' << p3 << ' ' << p4
                  << '\n'
                  << p5 << ' ' << p6 << ' ' << p7 << ' ' << p8
                  << '\n';
    }
};

template<typename T, std::size_t... indices>
auto generate_tuple(const std::vector<T>& v, std::index_sequence<indices...>) {
    return std::tuple{v[indices]...};
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
auto vector_to_tuple(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    return generate_tuple(v, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
    std::vector tetrahedron = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector prism = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    constexpr auto monster_generator = [](auto&&... args) {
        return Monster{std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...};
    };

    const auto m1 = std::apply(monster_generator, vector_to_tuple<4>(tetrahedron));
    const auto m2 = std::apply(monster_generator, vector_to_tuple<8>(prism));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Может написать что то вида ?

```
MyCentroid Get(vector<...> _Temp_points_for_centroid_points)
{
   if (_Temp_points_for_centroid_points.length() == 4)
     return Simple_value(Tetrahedron,
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[0],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[1],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[2],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[3]);
  if (_Temp_points_for_centroid_points.length() == 8)
    return Simple_value(Prism,
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[0],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[1],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[2],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[3],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[4],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[5],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[6],
                                   _Temp_points_for_centroid_points[7]);
   ///.....
}
```

Comment: У меня так и написано. Хочу уменьшить количество кода)

Comment: а сколько вариантов размера массива может быть?

Comment: посмотрите на это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994265/call-variadic-function-in-c-with-array-as-arguments

Comment: может быть 8 вариантов

Answer (score 1):

Не зная конструкторов `Simple_value` и того, что такое `Tetrahedron` и `Prism`, могу предложить такое решение:

```
#include <utility>        

template<typename T>
constexpr size_t points_count = 0;    

#define REGISTER_TYPE_TAG(Tag, Count) \
    template<> constexpr size_t points_count<struct Tag> = Count

REGISTER_TYPE_TAG(TetrahedronTag, 4);
REGISTER_TYPE_TAG(PrismTag, 8);


template<typename ... Ts, size_t ... Indexes>
Simple_value create_simple_value_impl(std::vector<YourPointType> const & points, std::index_sequence<Indexes...>, Ts && ... args)
{
    return Simple_value(std::forward<Ts>(args)..., points[Indexes]...);
}


template<typename TypeTag, typename ... Ts>
Simple_value create_simple_value(std::vector<YourPointType> const & points, Ts && ... args)
{
    static_assert(points_count<TypeTag> != 0, "invalid tag");
    return create_simple_value_impl(points, std::make_index_sequence<points_count<TypeTag>>(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}



//...
if(Tetrahedron)
    _Centroid_value = create_simple_value<TetrahedronTag>(_Temp_points_for_centroid_points, Tetrahedron);
if(Prism)
    _Centroid_value = create_simple_value<PrismTag>(_Temp_points_for_centroid_points, Prism);
```